# GWT: Two CellList style overlapped even with different css resource

Tags: gwt

In my GWT application I have two CellLists. Each with a different style, like below:

```
 public interface MyResources extends Resources
 {
    /**
     * The styles used in this widget.
     */
    @Override
    @Source( "com/example/CellList.css" )
    Style cellListStyle();
 }
 MyResources CELLLIST_RESOURCES = GWT.create( MyResources.class );

 ......
 mylist=new CellList<MyProxy>( myCell, CELLLIST_RESOURCES );
```

Both CellLists have different css files. But when loaded I found, the style of both lists was same. This is strange, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this [issue 6144](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144), the solution is simple, just use different interface name each, i.e.

```
interface TableResources extends CellTable.Resources
{
  @Source({"myCellTable.css"})
  TableStyle cellTableStyle();

}
```